# Do my bomb traps deal damage to my own buildings and walls?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I place bomb traps next to my walls or buildings and they get tripped by the enemy are they going to deal damage to my walls or buildings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you should be fine. The only damage they cause is to enemy troops.

Answer (score 4):

No, your bomb traps only deal damage to enemy but have no effect on your buildings.

Answer (score 4):

Nope not at all , the only thing the bombs should be dealing damage to is the enemy troops . Absolutely no effect to your buildings